# Contact form works but doesn't display value

Tags: php, email, checkbox

Everything works fine but it doesnt display position_label string on email and its value.
Can some check it and tell where's the problem? Tried many different solutions but non of them worked in this case.

HTML + Bootstrap 5

```
<form id="hire-form" name="hire-form" method="post" action="php/hire.php" role="form">
              <div class="position-hidden">
                <label class="modal-label" for="position">Position</label>
                <input id="hire_position" type="text" name="hire_position" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="mb-3 col-6">
                  <label class="modal-label" for="name_input">Name/Company*</label>
                  <input type="text" required maxlength="50" class="form-control modal-input" id="name_input"
                    name="hire_name_comp">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-4 col-6">
                  <label class="modal-label" for="phone_input">Phone/e-mail*</label>
                  <input type="tel" required maxlength="50" class="form-control modal-input" id="phone_input"
                    name="hire_phone_mail">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-1">
                <label for="text" class="position-label" for="position_input">Position is:</label>
                <div class="checkbox-new">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="position_label[check]" id="office_input" value="Office">
                  <label for="office_input">Office</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="position_label[check]" id="remote_input" value="Remote">
                  <label for="remote_input">Remote</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="position_label[check]" id="hybrid_input" value="Hybrid">
                  <label for="hybrid_input">Hybrid</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="modal-label" for="text">I have a job description</label>
                <input class="form-control modal-input" id="message" name="hire_link" placeholder="Paste link here">
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>*fields are obligatory</p>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger hundred-btn mt-3">Get me hundred
                candidates</button>
            </form>
```

Php

```
<?php
  
if($_POST) {
    $hire_position = "";
    $hire_name_comp = "";
    $hire_phone_mail = "";
    $position_label = "";
    $hire_link = "";
    $email_body = "<div><p><b>Just testin</b><br></p>";

    foreach($_POST['check[]'] as $value) {
        $check_msg .= "$value\n";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['hire_position'])) {
        $hire_position = filter_var($_POST['hire_position'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Looking for:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$hire_position."</span>
                        </div>";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['hire_name_comp'])) {
        $hire_name_comp = filter_var($_POST['hire_name_comp'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Name/Company:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$hire_name_comp."</span>
                        </div>";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['hire_phone_mail'])) {
        $hire_phone_mail = filter_var($_POST['hire_phone_mail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Phone/E-mail:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$hire_phone_mail."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
      
    if(isset($_POST['position_label'])) {
        $position_label = filter_var($_POST['position_label']);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Position is:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$check_msg."</span>
                        </div>";     
    }
      
    if(isset($_POST['hire_link'])) {
        $hire_link = filter_var($_POST['hire_link']);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Job description link:</b></label><div>".$hire_link."</div>
                        </div>";
    }
      
    $recipient = "test@test.eu";

    $email_body .= "</div>";
 
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"
    .'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"
    .'From: ' . $hire_phone_mail . "\r\n";
      
    if(mail($recipient, $hire_name_comp, $email_body, $headers)) {
        echo "<script>window.location = 'http://google.com/'</script>";

    } else {
        echo '<p>We are sorry but the email did not go through.</p>';
    }
      
} else {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, please try again.</p>';
}


?>
```

If someone can check this code and tell me where's the problem beacuse I've tried many different solutions and they didnt work.

EDITED:

It returns the right value 'Hybrid' so I have no idea whats wrong now... I mean there is still no info about this value in the email message. Its just empty.

```
array(5) { ["hire_position"]=> string(6) "JS Dev" ["hire_name_comp"]=> string(8) "Jeronimo" ["hire_phone_mail"]=> string(13) "danny@test.eu" ["position_label"]=> array(1) { ["check"]=> string(6) "Hybrid" } ["hire_link"]=> string(31) "http://google.com/" } array(5) { ["hire_position"]=> string(6) "JS Dev" ["hire_name_comp"]=> string(8) "Jeronimo" ["hire_phone_mail"]=> string(13) "danny@test.eu" ["position_label"]=> array(1) { ["check"]=> string(6) "Hybrid" } ["hire_link"]=> string(31) "http://google.com/" } array(5) { ["hire_position"]=> string(6) "JS Dev" ["hire_name_comp"]=> string(8) "Jeronimo" ["hire_phone_mail"]=> string(13) "danny@test.eu" ["position_label"]=> array(1) { ["check"]=> string(6) "Hybrid" } ["hire_link"]=> string(31) "http://google.com/" }
```

EDITED:

I think there is a problem with right usage of this value in the message.

EDITED:

PHP and HTML code updated.

Comment: There is no element in your form with `name="position_label"` so obviously `$_POST['position_label']` won't find anything. What is that intended to capture? Is it supposed to be the value(s) selected in the checkboxes, perhaps? I don't see anywhere else in the PHP code where you attempt to use those. You read them into `$check_msg`, but then you never do anything with that variable after that.

Comment: Yea ur right, there wasn't name att position_label. So Ive added it like this `position_label[check]` and now it displays "Position is:" , Ive also changed `$position_label = "";` variable but Im not sure how to code it in php to display checkboxes value in this case.

Comment: `foreach($_POST['check'] as $value) {
        $email_body .= "$value\n";
    }` (or something similar) will display the checkbox values in the email. Like I said, you're capturing those values already, but you aren't using them.

Comment: It didnt help, this value is still missing.

Comment: Try with `$_POST['check[]']` to match what's in the `name` in the HTML form

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` to debug and see what's actually in $_POST so you can see visually what you're trying to write the code against.

Comment: Imo everything looks fine...

Comment: According to that data, `$_POST['check']` only contains one value, so looping it would make no sense. But that's contrary to what's in the HTML form you've shown us, it doesn't make sense. Are you sure you've shown us the right HTML?

Comment: Also please update the code to show us how you're currently trying to include the "check" values into the email body

Comment: Yes, u r correct, previously I thought thats because I checked only one checkbox but now I know that it shows only the last value from array. HTML and PHP after changes updated.

Comment: It still doesn't match up. You've changed all the checkboxes to `name="position_label` but now your code is looking for `$_POST["check[]"]` and trying to put that in the email. The two halves of your code are going in opposite directions. We still don't have a [mre] of what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the name position_label in your form.

Moreover, If you want `$position_label = $check_msg;` you will have to put it after the foreach loop.

And your isset would be if(isset($position_label))

Comment: Yes you are right, there wasn't name attribute position_label. So Ive added it like this `position_label[check]` and now it displays "Position is:" , Ive also changed `$position_label = "";` variable but Im not sure how to code it in php to display checkboxes value in this case.